# Cannot write to socket before read

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

I have two sockets should send a packet, and listen for response.

Client Side (stt is Socket):

```
BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stt.getOutputStream()));
BufferedReader wrr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stt.getInputStream()));
if (i == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    wr.write("cnt\n");
    wr.write(s + "\n");
    
    #String s1 = wrr.readLine();
    #if (s1.equals("cnt")) {
    #    other = stt;
    #    startSc(MP);
    #}
} else wr.write("0");
wr.close();
wrr.close();
```

Server Side (inc is Socket):

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inc.getInputStream()));
BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(inc.getOutputStream()));
String correction = r.readLine(); //that line blocks
...
```

In this case (with lines with #); server side cannot get a packet.

If I remove lines with # in client side, the problem solves.

How can I read for response immediately after writing?

Comment: Of course it blocks, readLine it is blocking IO. How do you ensure that there is really anything for the server to read, you are not flushing the BufferedWriter. In addition, try waiting on the client Thread to actually ensure that the server actually receives what you sent.

Comment: @Ironluca if I remove lines with #, server can get the packets. So I'm sure server waiting for packets.

Comment: Ok, you are commenting (//) out the line that you indicate with #, well :D the wrr.readLine is blocking, there is noting to read (unless you are sending something from the server, not apparent from your code)

Comment: @Ironluca the problem is server doesn't read ```"cnt\n"``` and ```s + "\n"``` where it should read.

Comment: Great to know you tracked it :)